# ruby-on-rails: gravatar_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following the site http://railstutorial.org/
and in the chapter 7, it shows an example of how to
use gravatar_for.

I tried to use it using

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

but it does not render correctly in my browser (firefox/opera/chrome)

it render this html:

```
<div>classgravatartitleratingPGstylewidth:50px;height:50px;background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bebfcf57d6d8277d806a9ef3385c078d?rating=PG&amp;size=50) no-repeat;sslfalsealtdefault</div>
```

Could someone give me the solution for this problem? I got stuck and I really don't know to solve this. Thank very much.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
image_tag(gravatar_url(@user.email))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Listing 7.22 in the book](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#code%3auser_show_view_with_gravatar) uses the helper method **gravatar_image_tag** from the Gravatar gem:

> <%= gravatar_image_tag @user.email %>

Answer (score 1):

In your show you should paste smth like this:

```
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_image_tag @user.email %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
```

Or to use helper you should, copy this in `users_helper.rb`:

```
module UsersHelper

  def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50 })
    gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name,
                                            :class => 'gravatar',
                                            :gravatar => options)
  end
end
```

And then you can use this in your `app/views/users/show.html.erb`:

```
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem.

@JeffH: Fyi, I think we're looking at the [Rails2 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=2.3), not the Rails3. You can switch versions by clicking a button on the right side of the screen. [Listing 7.22](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two?version=2.3#code%3auser_show_view_with_gravatar) in the 2.3 version indeed says:

```
<h2>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= h @user.name %>
</h2>
```

codevoice's suggestion worked for me. Does anyone know why? Is it a versioning issue? For me, the command `<%= gravatar_for @user %>` generates the following html:

```
<div>stylewidth:50px;height:50px;background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bebfcf57d6d8277d806a9ef3385c078d?rating=PG&amp;size=50) no-repeat;classgravataraltratingPGdefaultsslfalsetitle</div>
```